# Time and "look back on" as a phrasal verb

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, syntactic-analysis, sense-verbs

When using this tri-part phrasal verb, i.e., "look back on," what is the length of time it refers to or can refer to? For example, it's common to say:

"When John looks back on his childhood, he can seen what a wonderful life he has had."

But using it for something recent "seems" intuitively odd:

"When John looks back on his meeting with Jane a minute ago, he realizes what he said was a bit rude."

So, is the general rule, use it with at least a week regarding past reference?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can be applied to any moment or period of time in the past, whether distant or recent past.